# How avoid having double loop?

Tags: ios, algorithm, typescript

From healthkit, I will receive some datas, for example steps data.

I save in my server this datas. Il have then an array of datas:

1.- startDate, endDate, value

2.- startDate, endDate, value

etc

It can be very lot of values in my server.

Then I get the values in the Healthkit. I have lot of values. Values who are in the server and new values.

I want to upload to the server only the new values.

I do so:

```
for each value in my server {
    for each value in healthkit{
        if(startDate, endDate and value are not equal to the value in the server){
            then save the value in the server
        }
    }
}
```

The algo will work, but it's very very slow. I can have lot of values in the two systems. Most of them the same in the two places.

Have you an idea how to do better?

I cannot save a flag in the healthKit.

I'm using ionic with angular 4 and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need a bit more context to understand the problem. By "new" values, are you including entries that have been modified, or just new entries that have been added?

If you only need the new values, and they are being added to the end of the array on the client side, then you can just take them from the end of the array.

```
const new_count = healthkit.length - myserver.length, // number of new entries
index_start = healthkit.length - new_count, // index in healthkit array where new entries start
new_values = healthkit.slice(index_start); // new array containing only new entries

addNewValues(new_values);
```

Now you have the new values in a separate array, and you can update them to the server.

If it is the case that you *do* need to update values that have changed, you can iterate over both arrays (only once, and at the same time) and find the differences. I am going to assume that the entries are in the same index for both arrays. I'm also assuming the "value" key is the only one you want to compare. You can do the following to find the values that have been modified.

```
const modified_values = [];
myserver.forEach(function(entry, i) { // iterate over server array
    let healthkit_entry = healthkit[i]; // get healthkit entry with same index
    if(entry.value !== healthkit_entry.value) { // see if value has changed
        modified_values.push(healthkit_entry); // if changed, add to modified array
    }
});

updateModifiedValues(modified_values);
```

Now the modified_values array has all of the modified entries from the healthkit array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that in the server it can have values from another application who don't come from Healthkit. Then we don't have same number of entries in both arrays

Comment: Can you determine which entries from the server are healthkit entries? If so, you can put them in a different array. Then you can sort them to make the entries have the same index as the healthkit array, if necessary. I think reorganizing the data somehow is the only way to avoid unnecessary looping. Can you describe the relationship between the two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the data on your server and the data from healthKit are sorted in the same way, or that you can sort them without affecting anything else.

For example you can sort your data on the server and the data from healthKit by StartDate, break ties by EndDate, then break ties by value.

Now you have two sorted arrays that you want to merge. The idea is to use the merge function of merge sort [explained here.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/)

You will end up with an array containing all the data without repetitions, which you can save on your server.

**Edit:**

```
void mergeArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[], int n1,
                             int n2, int arr3[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // Traverse both array
    while (i<n1 && j <n2)
    {
        // Check if current element of first
        // array is smaller than current element
        // of second array. If yes, store first
        // array element and increment first array
        // index. Otherwise do same with second array
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
        else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i]) 
            j++;
        else
            j++,i++;
    }

    // Store remaining elements of first array (healthKit Array)
    while (i < n1)
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we are close to a solution. But now for example if: I have array a = {a,b,c,e}, array b = {a,b,c,d} I will the obtain array result = {a,b,c,d,e}. Let say a is the array from the server, b the array from healthkit. c should have {d} because we only want to send the value who don't exist in server

Comment: I'm not familiar with dealing with servers but can't you change all the array instead of just adding?

Comment: Anyways it can be done, ill edit the answer with more details.

Comment: But he only wants `arr3` to contain the items that are in `arr1` and not in `arr2`. You need to modify your program so that things from `arr2` don't get copied to `arr3`. Also, your code will go into an infinite loop if `arr1[i] == arr2[j]`.

Comment: @jimMischel Thanks, fixed.